# Playing assets in just_audio for flutter web on Safari browser

Tags: flutter, just-audio

Hello Flutter developers,
I am trying to play a beeping noise that has a duration of 250 milliseconds at a frequency for 30 to 300 Hz. This is part of a simulated medical monitor. I have tried multiple audio packages and my most recent attempt is with just_audio, which works very well for every platform except the desktop safari browser. The app can be tested at benmed.org/sim (login required unfortunately).

Here is the audio playlist:

```
final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('asset:///assets/audio/beepfiles/98.wav')),
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('asset://assets//audio/beepfiles/96.wav')),
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('asset:///assets/audio/beepfiles/94.wav')),
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('asset:///assets/audio/beepfiles/92.wav')),
  ]);
```

Here is initilisation of the audio player:

```
Future\<void\> \_initAudio() async {
await player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());

try {
player.setAudioSource(playlist);
} catch (e) {
debugPrint("Error loading audio source: $e");
}
}
```

And here is the function that plays the beeping sounds with delays for variation in heart rate:

```
void playBeeps(WidgetRef ref) async {
    var obs = ref.watch(obsProvider);
    obs.whenData((obs) async {
      Future.doWhile(() async {
        var obs2 = ref.watch(testLocalObsProvider);
        int hr = obs2.heartRate;
        int sats = obs2.saturationsO2;
        bool audioIsMuted = ref.read(muteAudio);
        int track = (50 - ((sats / 2).round())).clamp(0, 15);
        player.seek(Duration.zero, index: track);
        await Future.delayed(
            Duration(milliseconds: ((60 / hr) * 1000).round()));
        player.play().catchError((e) {
          debugPrint(e);
        });
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 250));
        player.pause().catchError((e) {
          debugPrint(e);
        });
        return !audioIsMuted;
      });
    });
  }
```

1. I have tried just_audio among many other audio packages but nothing worked
2. I tried removing the "/assets" from the files
3. I tried .mp3 and .wav files

I wonder if the sequence of loading and playing the audio files is incorrect when compiled by safari.

Many thanks for your help with this issue.

Comment: It may also depend on when playBeeps is called. You may need to provide more details and what if any error message appears in the logs, and whether that error is associated with load or play.

Comment: Recheck the formatting of this section or correct the question. it's wrong .
`'asset:///assets/audio/beepfiles/98.wav'`